# How is the value of constant \$\zeta\$ calculated in the next second-order low-pass filter?

Tags: homework, active-filter

I was given a couple of problems about active filters, but unfortunately I have a little doubt about the resolution; the problem states:

> Design a second-order low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of 1 kHz, a \$\zeta\$ of 0.5, and a gain of 100. Use the equal-element approach."

So detailing the solution I did:

\$\omega_{0}=1~\mathrm{kHz}=6281.407~\mathrm{rad/s}\\  
\zeta=0.5\\  
K=100\$

I'm taking the gain as the DC gain (because this is not stated as the gain of the corner frequency). Since is the equal element way:

$$RC=\frac{1}{\omega_{0}}=\frac{1}{6281.407}=0.0001592~\mathrm{s}$$
$$\mu=3-2\zeta=3-2(0.5)=2$$

And the gain of the corner frequency:

$$|T(j\omega_{0})|=\frac{|K|}{2\zeta}$$
$$|T(j\omega_{0})|=\frac{|100|}{2(0.5)}=100$$

But reviewing the official solution it is stated that:

\$\omega_{0}=100000~\mathrm{rad/s}\\  
K=100\\   
|T(j\omega_{0})|=50\\
\zeta=\frac{100}{2(50)}=1\$

Then what value of \$\zeta\$ is (supposedly) right?

UPDATE:
Since this problem is inconsistent, as kindly noted by TimWestcott, I'm changing the question.

Comment: Those certainly don't match.  Either the problem is inconsistent with itself, or there's something you missed.

Comment: I have been trying to find it this comes from a book, but there are tons of statements alike.

Comment: The problem is that if you're assigned to design a filter with a specific value of \$\zeta\$, that's the right value.  If you finish designing your filter and it has a _different_ value of \$\zeta\$, then it's wrong.  So unless the problem statement has some allowance for relaxing the requirement on \$\zeta\$, then the problem statement and the provided answer _just don't match_.

Comment: Your design requires a value ζ, =0.5 which is identical to a pole-Q of "1". This means that you need a second-order lowpass with a complex pole pair. In this case you cannot simply set wo=1/RC.  You can use (a) either a classical RLC-topology or (b) an active opamp-based filter structure. The wording "equal element approach" means (most probably) that you should use an equal-component Sallen-Key topology. However, this solution does not allow a DC gain of "100".

Comment: @TimWescott, thanks I couldn't assess if this is an error but it seems it was stated this way.

Comment: @LvW, looking at others problems from the same class, the equal element method is the way to go. But as TimWescott says this is inconsistent. So I'm guessing it is a typo (?!).

Comment: @riccs_Ox Can you please explain (resp. confirm) what you mean with "equal element method" ? I ask this because this term alone does not specify a specific topology - however, it has a certain relation to the Sallen-Key method.

Comment: @LvW Yes, thanks, as far as I know the "equal element method" means/makes reference to the same thing as  "equal element approach" (at least in the notes, problems, exercises I'm reviewing).

Comment: @riccs_Ox Sorry, but this does not answer my question: Are you referring to the Sallen-Key topology only?

Comment: @LvW, short answer: I guess so; long answer, It seems the note makes reference to this topology, but in the case of the original question, I don't know.